# Guessing random number

Tags: java

I am in the process of learning Java, at least i am trying.
Now i made an app where you need to guess the random number generated with math.random.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class var {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //var definitie
        int player;
        int rnummer;

        rnummer = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);

        System.out.println("Raad het nummer!");
        player = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(rnummer);

        //goed geraden check
        if (player == rnummer) {
            System.out.println("Helaas, dat is niet juist.");
            player = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Goed geraden!");
    }
}
```

Now there is a problem where every time you guess it is right, you cannot guess wrong.
I cannot figure out the problem.. it must be very simple.

Comment: What do you mean by `every time you guess it is right, you cannot guess wrong` ?

Comment: The flow seems quite simple: If the nummer was correct (==) then a error message is displayed ("dat is niet juist.") and then another number is read. Then the positive output is displayed ("Goed geraden!").

Comment: Still, no matter wich number i type in it is always good, even when i print the random generated number and type something else than that..

Comment: This is not a Java problem but an algorithm problem. You need to understand the concept of condition and loop. Those are quite different

Comment: Please provide the expected output and what output you actually get.

Comment: That `Goed geraden` is printed no matter you guessed it or not. Is that your problem

Comment: How do i go about fixing this?

Comment: Fixing what ? We have no idea what you are trying to achieve ? Give some sample Output as Suggested by @skyking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to understand that statement :

```
if (player == rnummer) 
{
     System.out.println("Helaas, dat is niet juist.");
     player = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

This means :

```
if player is equals to rnummer
then 
     print "Helaas, dat is niet juist."
     ask a value and store it in player
and read the next line
```

But what you want is

```
if player is NOT equals to rnummer
then
     print "Helaas, dat is niet juist."
     ask a value and store it in player
check again the condition
```

This is what we call a loop. This is similar than an `if` but will only exit the statement when the condition is false.

```
while(player != rnummer) 
{
    System.out.println("Helaas, dat is niet juist.");
    player = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

An `if` only execute the block statement once if the condition is true.

A `while` will execute the block until the condition is false.

NOTE : Since a loop only end when the condition is false (not completly true, some keywords can exit those, but this is an other subject), you can end up with an infinite loop, that means the condition will NEVER be false.

```
while(true){
    //Statement
}
// Unreachable code
```

Comment: That makes it quite easy to understand, wish there would be more websites/books that would explain it like that.

Comment: @Luukwa, I have just add a small comment about while loop, this should be interesting to prevent some unexpected bug ;)

Comment: Thanks, will help a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to substitute the `if` statement with a `while` loop:

```
while (player != rnummer) {
    System.out.println("Helaas, dat is niet juist.");
    player = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

that in natual language can be tranlated in "While your guess is different from the random number, keep trying". 
If you use only an if, the code inside the {} brackets will be executed only if the condition it's true, but after that the program will continue with the next instruction that is `System.out.println("Goed geraden!");` in your code.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks! Not yet into loops.. that why i used an if.

Comment: @Luukwa no problem, we are all here to learn ^^ I added a brief explanation, I hope it can be useful :)